# Return values from nested functions

Tags: javascript, arrays

Consider the following example:

```js
const colour = garage.find(car => car.colours.find(colour => colour.primary === value));
```

This snippet returns the *top most parent* object if the conditions of the  inner functions are all met i.e. the search value is matched.

**What's the most elegant way to return the inner-most child's value i.e. the matched "node"?**

All I can think of is the following and I hate it:

```js
const car = garage.find(car => car.colours.find(colour => colour.primary === value));
const colour = car.colours.find(colour => colour.primary === value);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a `for` loop instead:

```
for (const car of garage) {
  for (const color of car.colours) {
    if (colour.primary === value) {
      return colour;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could flatten the array to an array of colours, then find:

```
  const colour = garage
    .flatMap(car => car.colours)
    .find(colour => colour.primary === value);
```